# What is the process to Degrade/rollback to datastax cassandra lower version?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0

I want to degrade my datastax cassandra enterprise version from 5.0.15 to 4.8.16 to list down the rollback process in case of any emergency.

Please help me to list down the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before performing upgrade it's always recommended to perform backup of existing data, and if something went wrong, then you can restore data from snapshots - the precise steps will depend on how you did perform backup - via OpsCenter, or with `nodetool snapshot`.

See [DSE upgrade guide](https://docs.datastax.com/en/upgrade/doc/upgrade/datastax_enterprise/upgdDSE50.html#upgdDSE50__recommendations) for additional information about upgrade.

P.S. DataStax support's KB has very good article on the ["manual" backup/restore](https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001593706-Manual-Backup-and-Restore-with-Point-in-time-and-table-level-restore-) - I recommend to follow it if you won't use OpsCenter for backup.